# How to cast an output of a Filter in VTK in C++ with QT?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am using VTK to render an depth image, and have set up the connections. However, when it comes to saving the output of the renderer as png file I get the warning, that the PngWriter only supports unsigned char and unsigned short inputs.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter> imageWriter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter>::New();
imageWriter->SetInputConnection(zFilter->GetOutputPort());
imageWriter->SetFileName( qPrintable(QString("outdepth_%1.png").arg(i)) );
imageWriter->Write();
```

This is my code (inside a loop) , basically I need sth like `(unsigned short) zFilter->GetOutputPort()` - which of course does  not makye *any* sense at all, it is just for clarification what should be casted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vtkImageCast](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageCast.html) to cast image from scalar type that `zFilter` produces to `unsigned short`.

For that purpose you can use `vtkImageCast::SetOutputScalarTypeToUnsignedShort()`.

Your code will then look something like this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageCast> cast = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageCast>::New();
cast->SetInputConnection(zFilter->GetOutputPort());
cast->SetOutputScalarTypeToUnsignedShort();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter> imageWriter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter>::New();
imageWriter->SetInputConnection(cast->GetOutputPort());
imageWriter->Write();
```